# Transfer function of cyclic block diagram

Tags: transfer-function, block-diagram

I have this block diagram, and I just can't arrive at the transfer function \$H(s) = \frac{y(s)}{u(s)} \$
[image]

Starting from the end, we see that
$$y(s) = xC $$
Let's find out what x is.
$$x=\Bigg[\bigg(u(s)-x\bigg)A-y(s) \Bigg]B $$
But as you can see from the equation, it is recursive. I also can't see how the block diagram can be simplified, since nothing is in series or parallel. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: It's just algebra, Carl, to solve for \$x\$. Different people will have slightly different preferences. But they all learned to do it. The equation is recursive only if you substitute over and over for \$x\$. But for solving for \$x\$ you can just expand all of factors on the right hand side into individual terms, then collect terms that include \$x\$ as a factor onto the left hand side, factor out \$x\$, and then divide both sides with remaining cofactor of \$x\$. You did well in stating the issue, though!

Comment: Thank you @jonk , I solved it using the block diagram reduction method suggested by AJN and it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second equation contains a term \$ -x\cdot A \cdot B\$ in the RHS. Take the \$ -x\cdot A \cdot B\$ from the second equation to its LHS. Then, substitute for `x` in the first equation with `x` from the (now re arranged) second equation. This eliminates the variable `x` in the final equation.

### Other methods

Apart from the above manual elimination of variables, there are two more methods. *Block diagram reduction techniques* and *Mason Gain Formula*. If you are familiar with either technique, use one which is convenient.

### Block diagram reduction

Shift the junction labelled `x` to the right of the `C` block by using an additional `1/C` block in the feedback path. Now you have nested feedbacks. Use the `G/(1+GH)` feedback formula on the innermost loop and repeat until no more loops remain.